# Can I route all network connections through a virtual machine on macosx?

Tags: macos, networking, virtual-machine, monitoring

So far I've experienced with proxy software to monitor http connections on my machine, but I want to know about every little detail. I thought I could install a virtual machine and force macosx to route all network connections through this virtual machine, and run there a linux with network sniffing software. The idea being the linux machine would see every connection.

Is this possible at all? After all, the virtual machine itself is just another process more from the point of macosx. Maybe there is a way to allow network connections to work only for a specific process so that everything else either failed or was routed through the virtual machine?

Comment: Maybe use bridged networking and give the real one an IP that can't connect to anything and the virtual machine the IP of the real machine. Then give the virtual machine another host-networked network card that only communicates with the host. Now you can route everything using iptables